# Export P12 from GnuPG for PDF signing field

Tags: pdf, gnupg, pgp, digital-signature

It seems to be possible to export a PGP .asc file to .p12, but I'm unable to use the generated .p12 file for a signature field in a PDF file. Is there a way to export it so it's usable for that field, or is it somehow restricted and doesn't allow this at all?